# How to query all association (all level) in Neo4j?

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases, fraud-prevention

I am new to study graph databases (using Neo4j), I am modelling for my project. The business rule is that we need to store the users and devices they used, and this is my current model:

Account A uses device D: `(Account A) -[USED]-> (Device D)`

Account B also uses device D: `(Account B) -[USED]-> (Device D)`

=>

`(Account A) -[USED]-> (Device D) <-[USED]- (Account B)`

In future, account B will use other devices & be related with other accounts.

My questions are:

1. Is it a good model in this case?
2. With this model, how to find all associated account with account A?

Thank for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this model works, as :Account and :Device nodes are distinct in the graph.

As for figuring out what other accounts that are associated with :Account a (only considering the link via using the same device), simple queries should do the trick. Assuming we have :Account(name) in the graph, and that there's an index on this (for fast lookup of :Account nodes by name), we could use this:

```
MATCH (:Account {name:'A'})-[:USED]->()<-[:USED]-(other:Account)
RETURN DISTINCT other
```

If :USED relationships always are incoming to :Device nodes, we could simplify this to:

```
MATCH (:Account {name:'A'})-[:USED*2]-(other:Account)
RETURN DISTINCT other
```

If we also needed the devices used in common between the two connected account nodes, we could include that as a collection of the nodes between the two linked accounts:

```
MATCH (:Account {name:'A'})-[:USED]->(device)<-[:USED]-(other:Account)
RETURN other, collect(device) as sharedDevices
```